# I cannot seem to find the error here that's causing this malfunction

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, runtime-error, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to interface 4 different HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Sensors and I'm facing some issues regarding this error

*"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/multipleultrasonic.py", line 41, in 
pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
NameError: name 'pulse_start' is not defined"*

I tried a lot of solutions from here and even other links on the web but I am unable to resolve the issue. I am a beginner with Python which adds to the confusion.Can anybody help me with this error please?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
TRIG1 = 24
ECHO1 = 23
TRIG2 = 8
ECHO2 = 25
TRIG3 = 0
ECHO3 = 7
TRIG4 = 5
ECHO4 = 1
def take_measurement():
  global TRIG, ECHO
  pulse_start = pulse_end = 0
print ("Distance Measurement In Progress")
GPIO.setup(TRIG1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO1,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(TRIG2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO2,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(TRIG3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO3,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(TRIG4,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO4,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(TRIG1, False)
GPIO.output(TRIG2, False)
GPIO.output(TRIG3, False)
GPIO.output(TRIG4, False)
print ("Waiting For Sensor 1 To Send Signal")
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(TRIG1, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG1, False)
print ("Reading Sensor 1")
while GPIO.input(ECHO1)==0:
    pulse_start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO1)==1:
    pulse_end = time.time()
pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
distance = pulse_duration * 17150
distance = round( distance,2)
print ("Distance Sensor 1:"+str(distance)+"cm")
print ("Waiting for Sensor 2 to send signal")
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(TRIG2, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG2, False)
print ("Reading Sensor 2")
while GPIO.input(ECHO2)==0:
    pulse_start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO2)==1:
    pulse_end = time.time()
pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
distance = pulse_duration * 17150
distance = round( distance,2)
print ("Distance Sensor 2:"+str(distance)+"cm")
print ("Waiting for Sensor 3 to send signal")
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(TRIG3, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG3, False)
print ("Reading Sensor 3")
while GPIO.input(ECHO3)==0:
    pulse_start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO3)==1:
    pulse_end = time.time()
pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
distance = pulse_duration * 17150
distance = round( distance,2)
print ("Distance Sensor 3:"+str(distance)+"cm")
print ("Waiting for Sensor 4 to send signal")
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(TRIG4, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG4, False)
print ("Reading Sensor 4")
while GPIO.input(ECHO4)==0:
    pulse_start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO4)==1:
    pulse_end = time.time()
pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
distance = pulse_duration * 17150
distance = round( distance,2)
print ("Distance Sensor 4:"+str(distance)+"cm")
print ("Waiting for Sensor 4 to send signal")

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Intendation is important in python. If the code really looks as above, there's something wrong with it. The `take_measurement()` function should probably go to right before the `GPIO.cleanup()`. And then you need to call it, too.

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the help.
The code looks a lot like this but it has definitely changed in indentation while posting here. I'll give your suggestion a try and let you know what happens.
One quick question: Will the remaining code follow the new indent (i.e. one right indent after the take_measurement() function), or do I have to remove the indent after some function?

Comment: If I understand the code correctly (or what it should do), you should add an indent up until the `GPIO.cleanup()` (and of course insert a call to `take_measurement()` there). In addition, you should remove the `print("Reading Sensor...")`lines, as they influence the measurement.